# Selling properties while owing another player

Tags: monopoly

Can I sell properties to a player while I have to pay another player? 
I was wondering if I land on a player's building and I have to pay him or her but I don't have money, however I have a property that another player would like to buy. Can I sell it to this player?

Comment: [this answer](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/28065/trading-property-to-settle-a-debt-in-monopoly) as well as [this one](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/28065/trading-property-to-settle-a-debt-in-monopoly) are related.

Answer (score 2):

You can sell houses and hotels to the bank (at 50% value).

You can sell empty property to another player even if it is mortgaged.

> **SELLING PROPERTY**... Unimproved properties, railroads and utilities
> (but not buildings) may be sold to any player as a private transaction
> for any amount the owner can get; however, no property can be sold to
> another player if buildings are standing on any properties of that
> color-group. Any buildings so located must be sold back to the Bank
> before the owner can sell any property of that color-group.
>
> Houses and
> hotels may be sold back to the Bank at any time for one-half  the
> price paid for them. All houses on one color-group must be sold one by
> one, evenly, in reverse of the manner in which they were erected. All
> hotels on one color-group may be sold at once, or they may be sold one
> house  at a time (one hotel equals five houses), evenly, in reverse of
> the manner in which they were erected.
>
> **MORTGAGES**... Unimproved
> properties can be mortgaged through the Bank at any time. Before an
> improved property can be mortgaged, all the buildings on all the
> properties of its color-group must be sold back to the Bank at half
> price. The mortgage value is printed on each Title Deed card. No rent
> can be collected on mortgaged properties or utilities, but rent can be
> collected on unmortgaged properties in the same group.
>
> In order to
> lift the mortgage, the owner must pay the Bank the amount of the
> mortgage  plus  10% interest. When all the properties of a color-group
> are no longer mortgaged, the owner may begin to buy back houses at
> full price. The player who mortgages property retains possession of it
> and no other player may secure it by lifting the mortgage from the
> Bank. However, the owner may sell this mortgaged property to another
> player at any agreed price. If you are the new owner, you may lift the
> mortgage at once if you wish by paying off the mortgage plus 10%
> interest to the Bank. If the mortgage is not lifted at once, you must
> pay the Bank 10% interest when you buy the property and if you lift
> the mortgage later you must pay the Bank an  additional  10% interest
> as well as the amount of the mortgage.
>
> **BANKRUPTCY**... You are dec

Comment: This post answers a question entirely different from the one asked by OP..